# Disable HTTP requests unless they go through WebMock

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webmock

I'm trying to make sure that all HTTP requests go through WebMock. I would expect this code to fail with some sort of WebMock exception, but it executes just fine:

```
require "test_helper"
require "webmock/minitest"

class URLTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  test "valid urls" do
    WebMock.enable!
    WebMock.disable_net_connect!
    Net::HTTP.get("www.google.com", "/") # Should raise WebMock::NetConnectNotAllowedError
  end
end
```

How can I ensure that all HTTP requests are going through WebMock?

I am using Rails 7.2, Ruby 3.22, and VCR 6.2.0.

Here is my VCR config:

```
  VCR.configure do |c|
    c.cassette_library_dir = Rails.root.to_s + "/test/vcr_cassettes"
    c.hook_into :webmock
    c.allow_http_connections_when_no_cassette = true
    c.default_cassette_options= {:serialize_with => :yaml, :record => :once, :allow_playback_repeats => true}
  end
```

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the issue in isolation. [Example](https://replit.com/@engineersmnky/ShockingWarpedQuote#main.rb) Maybe there is a configuration error somewhere?

Comment: Thanks @engineersmnky ! That helped me figure out that it must be related to my test configuration where I use VCR. Sure enough disabling VCR fixes the issues. Do you know how I can get this to work as expected without dropping VCR?

Comment: @TomRossi can you post your VCR configuration as well as the test block that was not working so that we get a better idea of the context?

Comment: @engineersmnky I updated my post and have the VCR config at the bottom.

Comment: Seems this has been an "issue" for some time [499](https://github.com/vcr/vcr/issues/499). [146](https://github.com/vcr/vcr/issues/146) seems to offer some workarounds but this does not seem like something VCR supports naturally.

Comment: @engineersmnky VCR.turn_off! did it! Post it as an answer and I'll accept!

Comment: Since you actually implemented the solution please feel free to answer your own question as all I did was some research but I do not use either library frequently enough to provide a reasonable answer.